# group & split xml file using result-document, not working

Tags: xml, xslt, split, saxon

I am looking for your kind help to group and split my MxML file.

Below is my sample XML where I would like to group and split into multiple chunks. 
My MxML file has multiple ccy pairs and maturity sets. When I process the file as a whole it takes a time, so idea is group on pair and split the file into multiple smaller chuks (which will be configurable).

Data file... xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GuiRoot>
    <xc:XmlCache xmlns:xc="XmlCache" xc:action="Update">
        <xc:XmlCacheArea xc:value="MarketParameters">
            <mp:nickName xmlns:mp="mx.MarketParameters" xc:value="./BORATES" xc:subset="Reference">
                <mp:date xc:value="TODAY">
                    <fx:forex xmlns:fx="mx.MarketParameters.Forex">
                        <fxsm:smile xmlns:fxsm="mx.MarketParameters.Forex.Smile">
                            <fxsm:pair xc:value="pair1">
                                <fxsm:maturity xc:value="10Y">
                                    <fxsm:ordinate xc:type="Fields" xc:value="10.000000000">
                                        <mp:bid xc:type="Field" xc:keyFormat="N">0.9236</mp:bid>
                                        <mp:ask xc:type="Field" xc:keyFormat="N">0.9236</mp:ask>
                                    </fxsm:ordinate>
                                </fxsm:maturity>
                                <fxsm:maturity xc:value="1Y">
                                    <fxsm:ordinate xc:type="Fields" xc:value="90.000000000">
                                        <mp:bid xc:type="Field" xc:keyFormat="N">3.4369</mp:bid>
                                        <mp:ask xc:type="Field" xc:keyFormat="N">3.4369</mp:ask>
                                    </fxsm:ordinate>
                                </fxsm:maturity>
                            </fxsm:pair>
                            <fxsm:pair xc:value="pair2">
                                <fxsm:maturity xc:value="10Y">
                                    <fxsm:ordinate xc:type="Fields" xc:value="10.000000000">
                                        <mp:bid xc:type="Field" xc:keyFormat="N">3.4369</mp:bid>
                                        <mp:ask xc:type="Field" xc:keyFormat="N">3.4369</mp:ask>
                                    </fxsm:ordinate>
                                </fxsm:maturity>
                                <fxsm:maturity xc:value="1Y">
                                    <fxsm:ordinate xc:type="Fields" xc:value="90.000000000">
                                        <mp:bid xc:type="Field" xc:keyFormat="N">3.4369</mp:bid>
                                        <mp:ask xc:type="Field" xc:keyFormat="N">3.4369</mp:ask>
                                    </fxsm:ordinate>
                                </fxsm:maturity>
                            </fxsm:pair>
                            <fxsm:pair xc:value="pair3">
                                <fxsm:maturity xc:value="10Y">
                                    <fxsm:ordinate xc:type="Fields" xc:value="10.000000000">
                                        <mp:bid xc:type="Field" xc:keyFormat="N">3.4369</mp:bid>
                                        <mp:ask xc:type="Field" xc:keyFormat="N">3.4369</mp:ask>
                                    </fxsm:ordinate>
                                </fxsm:maturity>
                                <fxsm:maturity xc:value="1Y">
                                    <fxsm:ordinate xc:type="Fields" xc:value="90.000000000">
                                        <mp:bid xc:type="Field" xc:keyFormat="N">3.4369</mp:bid>
                                        <mp:ask xc:type="Field" xc:keyFormat="N">3.4369</mp:ask>
                                    </fxsm:ordinate>
                                </fxsm:maturity>
                            </fxsm:pair>
                            <fxsm:pair xc:value="pair4">
                                <fxsm:maturity xc:value="10Y">
                                    <fxsm:ordinate xc:type="Fields" xc:value="10.000000000">
                                        <mp:bid xc:type="Field" xc:keyFormat="N">3.4369</mp:bid>
                                        <mp:ask xc:type="Field" xc:keyFormat="N">3.4369</mp:ask>
                                    </fxsm:ordinate>
                                </fxsm:maturity>
                                <fxsm:maturity xc:value="1Y">
                                    <fxsm:ordinate xc:type="Fields" xc:value="90.000000000">
                                        <mp:bid xc:type="Field" xc:keyFormat="N">3.4369</mp:bid>
                                        <mp:ask xc:type="Field" xc:keyFormat="N">3.4369</mp:ask>
                                    </fxsm:ordinate>
                                </fxsm:maturity>
                            </fxsm:pair>
                        </fxsm:smile>
                    </fx:forex>
                </mp:date>
            </mp:nickName>
        </xc:XmlCacheArea>
    </xc:XmlCache>
</GuiRoot>
```

My XSLT (not working)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"  
xmlns:fxsm="mx.MarketParameters.Forex.Smile"
xpath-default-namespace="mx.MarketParameters.Forex.Smile"  xmlns:xc="xmlCache" exclude-result-prefixes="xs math" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
   <!--  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/> -->
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <!-- define variables  [start] -->
   <xsl:variable name="noOfSplits" select="3"/>
   <!-- define variables  [end] -->
   <!--- an alternative to shallow-copy in xslt 2.0 -->
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <!--- an alternative to shallow-copy in xslt 2.0 -->
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="original-root-element" select="*"/>
      <xsl:variable name="groups">
         <xsl:for-each-group select="//pair" group-by="@xc:value">
            <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
               <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/maturity" group-by="@xc:value">
                  <xsl:copy>
                     <xsl:copy-of select="@*, current-group()/node()"/>
                  </xsl:copy>
               </xsl:for-each-group>
            </xsl:copy>
         </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="$groups/pair" group-by="(position() - 1) mod $noOfSplits">
         <xsl:result-document href="files/split{position()}.xml">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$original-root-element">
               <xsl:with-param name="contents" select="current-group()" tunnel="yes"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
         </xsl:result-document>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="//smile">
      <xsl:param name="contents" tunnel="yes"/>
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:copy-of select="$contents"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Kindly appriciate your help to understand what is wrong with above code....

thanks in advance

Comment: Well, you will have to shorten the input to the minimum data you need to demonstrate the problem and then you need to show the result you want for that input. Simply telling us the XSLT is "not working" does not explain which result you want and why you have written or copied the presented XSLT which seems to try to group various elements. Also, as you mention Saxon and want to split files, perhaps using to Saxon 9.8 and XSLT 3 makes your task easier, see http://xslt-3-by-example.blogspot.de/2017/06/extracting-sub-trees-of-document-using.html

Comment: Please don't tell us something "isn't working". We need to know how it fails.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the reply....

Comment: apologies for not being clear, looks some issue with my internet connection and my comment didn't get submitted properly... I am using saxon-he-9.4.0.7.jar. 

Yes I would like to split the files based on the value of fxsm:pair.

I expect 

pair3 in files/split0.xml
pair1 & pair4 to be in files/split1.xml and
pair2 to be in files/split2.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than just give you the answer, I'm going to talk you through my process of debugging it: hopefully that will be more instructive.

First I ran the transformation from the command line, with the -t option. It produced no output on the console other than an XML declaration, and the -t output didn't show any secondary output files being written.

Then I ran with the -T option (which often produces very voluminous trace output). This time it produced a very short trace file:

```
<trace saxon-version="9.8.0.6" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <source node="/" line="0" file="test.xml">
  <xsl:template match="/" line="20" column="29" module="test.xsl">
   <xsl:variable name="original-root-element" line="21" column="64" module="test.xsl">
    <xsl:variable name="groups" line="22" column="37" module="test.xsl">
     <xsl:for-each-group line="23" column="70" module="test.xsl">
     </xsl:for-each-group>
     <xsl:for-each-group line="34" column="95" module="test.xsl">
     </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:variable>
   </xsl:variable>
  </xsl:template>
 </source><!-- / -->
</trace>
```

This indicates that the xsl:for-each-group on line 23 isn't selecting anything. I confirmed this with an xsl:message displaying the value of the variable $groups.

I tried changing the `select` expression to use the namespace explicitly (`select="//Q{mx.MarketParameters.Forex.Smile}pair"`) which made no difference.

I then tried the same XPath expression `//Q{mx.MarketParameters.Forex.Smile}pair` in oXygen and it selected four `pair` elements.

I tried `//*:pair` and `.//*:pair` and `.//*:smile/*` - still no luck.

I added an `<xsl:message select=".//*:pair"/>` before the for-each-group and it outputs four `pair` elements.

Aha! There's another reason that for-each-group can produce empty output: it selects the elements OK, but they have no grouping keys. The grouping key is @xc:value, which appears to exist in the source document. But if we look more carefully, the source document has `xmlns:xc="XmlCache"`, while the stylesheet has `xmlns:xc="xmlCache"`.

So, a simple error. As this exercise demonstrates, these can be hard to pin down. The only real answer to this is to use schema-aware XSLT coding - this would probably have allowed the XSLT compiler to spot the error. Sadly, the only time people realise this is when they have just spent several hours debugging such a problem, and at that point they've got far too much to do to invest time in making sure it doesn't happen again.

Comment: thanks a lot Michael, this was very much useful. However after making changes in my 
xslt... xmlns:xc="XmlCache", still it didn't produce any files...

Comment: @PanduranG, I have tried the stylesheet you posted with the fix Michael suggested against your input with Saxon 9 and the `-t` option and it shows it writes three result files `files/split1.xml`, `files/split2.xml`, `files/split3.xml`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I am using  saxon-he-9.4.0.7.jar., did you used the same?

Was the fix you applied only below line?

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"  
xmlns:xc="XmlCache" 
xmlns:fxsm="mx.MarketParameters.Forex.Smile"
xpath-default-namespace="mx.MarketParameters.Forex.Smile"  
exclude-result-prefixes="xs math" version="2.0">